# How to tag tests in Jasmine Javascript

Tags: javascript, testing, junit, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I wanted to make a similar behaviour of the `@Tag` annotation of *JUnit* to Tag/Filter specific test methods / classes but in Jasmine Javascript.

I read some articles related to this, that mentioned to add the keyword I want to tag with in the `describe` or `it` of the test in Jasmine, for example:

```
it('should travel back in time #back', () => { 
  expect(travelBack({now: 2016}, 16)).toEqual({now: 2000}) 
})
```

#back here plays the tag role.
And to execute it in `karma-jasmine` for example I need to add in the `karma.conf.js` this `attribute` in the `config.set`:  `client: { args: ['--grep', '#back'] }`

Is there a better way to apply this logic if I wanted to make it more dynamic?
If I wanted to pass this tag value which is `#back` here as a dynamic value, like each run I want to pass a different tag through the CLI for the karma.config.js to pick and apply instead of changing in the karma.conf.js itself each time?